# Arduino serial read and check

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to learn some things about arduino serial reading from a bluetooth device. This is the code I found everywhere:

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data

void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {

        // send data only when you receive data:
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
                // read the incoming byte:
                incomingByte = Serial.read();

                // say what you got:
                Serial.print("I received: ");
                Serial.println(incomingByte);
        }
}
```

When I send the word "word" from my mobile bluetooth I get 4 lines:

I received: w

I received: o

I received: r

I received: d

which is fine... But here 's my question:

I want to check the received characters as soon as they come into the serial input, so if one of them is the character "r", I would like an extra line to be printed in the Serial Monitor, something like: "wow, that was an r!"

So I add an if statement after the println(incomingByte) and my code is now like that:

```
Serial.print("I received: ");
Serial.println(incomingByte);
if (incomingByte == "r") {
    Serial.println("wow, that was an r!");
}
```

That code never works, it 's like not having an "r" at all.
Could someone explain to me?
Thanks

Comment: in cpp (which is the language arduino is based of), double quotes (") make a string, which inherently is an array of characters and therefore, the int value of "r" is just the location where the program stored the array. you should try using single quotes for this (as it is a single character), so `if (incomingByte == 'r')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is due to the usage of `"r"` instead of `'r'`. The difference is that in first case you have string, which is char[], and in the second you have single char.

Comment: Thank you, you 're right

Comment: Edit: Oh, `"X"` is obviously a string, and `'X'` is char. Sorry I unconsciously wrote it backwards.